# What will happen if two kernel module export same symbol

Tags: linux-kernel

If two  kernel module contain EXPORT_SYMBOL(a),  a is defined as: int a, what will happen if two module was inserted? which "a" will be used?

Comment: I would hope the compile of the kernel fails with a duplicate error.

Comment: You should consider selecting an answer as correct. You know, be a good stackoverflow citizen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't insert duplicate symbols into the kernel. Example:

### The `xor` module loaded in my kernel

```
nwatkins@kyoto:~$ lsmod | grep xor
xor                     4685  1 async_xor
```

### The exported `xor_blocks` symbol in the `xor` module

```
nwatkins@kyoto:~$ nm /lib/modules/2.6.32-24-generic/kernel/crypto/xor.ko  | grep xor_blocks
0000000000000000 r __kcrctab_xor_blocks
0000000000000000 r __kstrtab_xor_blocks
0000000000000000 r __ksymtab_xor_blocks
0000000000000bb0 T xor_blocks
```

### Another exported `xor_blocks` symbol in a module I created

```
nwatkins@kyoto:~$ nm mod-t1.ko  | grep xor
0000000000000000 r __kcrctab_xor_blocks
0000000000000000 r __kstrtab_xor_blocks
0000000000000000 r __ksymtab_xor_blocks
0000000000000000 T xor_blocks
```

### Error reported from `insmod`

```
nwatkins@kyoto:~$ sudo insmod mod-t1.ko 
insmod: error inserting 'mod-t1.ko': -1 Invalid module format
```

### Duplicate error message from `dmesg`

```
[422002.174033] mod_t1: exports duplicate symbol xor_blocks (owned by xor)
```