# How to load a modified kernel module which is already exist in precompiled kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, kbuild

one way is to do so is to build the kernel sources again with making original module loadable which need to be modified. so original module can be removed and modified module can be inserted. but this is time consuming process.
I am wondering if there is some other way to load modified module.

I made some modification in MD driver and tried to load it on precompiled kernel.
insmod failed with following error messege:

> md_mod: exports duplicate symbol bitmap_close_sync (owned by kernel)
>   insmod: error inserting 'md-mod.ko': -1 Invalid module format

Please provide the feedback if it can be done. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error shows up because already the **bitmap_close_sync symbol is exported by the kernel**, again you are trying to **re-export** the same symbol in md_mod module. Try not to export the symbol, compile and try inserting the module (module should be compiled against the kernel version on which it is inserted). Go through stackoverflow link [What will happen if two kernel module export same symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454740/what-will-happen-if-two-kernel-module-export-same-symbol). Hope it answers your question :-).

Comment: this is not exactly what i was looking for...but i like the idea of not exporting the symbol...thanks.

Comment: anyway my problem is solved as md modules are loadable by default...but load on boot time...so i mistaken them as in built with kernel image.